# Can I use Docker to use write code on MacOS and then run the code on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, docker, raspberry-pi

I have just started reading about Docker and haven't used it yet. But I want to find out if it can solve my problem before I dive into the details of how to solve it.

I want to write some python code on MacOS using packages like sktime and others. Then I want to put all the code and the dependencies in a container. I want to use this container on a Raspberry Pi and run my code on it.

I end up running into dependencies issues with numpy when I try to install the required packages like sktime through pip on the Raspberry Pi. (As sktime requires `numpy > 1.21.0` while `sudo apt-get install python3-numpy` installs `numpy==`1.19.5`.)

Will these same problems occur even when using a Docker container?

Basically I want to skip the hassle of figuring out how to install the required dependencies on a Raspberry Pi.

P.S: The code does audio processing on a audio stream from a microphone.

EDIT: Opinions if not exact answers from experienced Docker users is welcome too!

Comment: Accessing host devices like the microphone can be a tricky problem on its own.  Before investing too much time in a Docker setup, would it work to use a Python virtual environment instead?  (Use Python-native tools like `pip` to install dependencies, don't try to install them using an OS package manager like APT.)

Comment: I have figured out accessing the microphone using `portaudio` library for which the python `sounddevice` library provides a good interface. By Python virtual environment, do you mean that I should simulate my Raspberry Pi environment on my MacOS using venv etc? I tried using `pip`. But it leads down a deep hole full of import problems,  `numba` throws an `AttributeError` as it's incompatible with latest version of `'numpy`. I can't update `numba` as there's some issue with `llvmlite`. All this is avoided if I install `numpy` using APT. Hence, my question.